# Jenkins pipeline seed job using a wildcard with a Jenkinsfile

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I am building Jenkins pipeline using CasC. I'm fairly new to Groovy and all related pipelines stuff and not sure what terminology I should be using. My goal is to pull in jobs from:

```
https://gitlab.domain.com/<repo>/project.git
```

Repo path:

```
<repo>/jobs
```

using the following in the Jenkins CasC yaml file:

```
jobs:
  - script: >
      folder('App')
  - file: /var/jenkins_home/pipelines/pull_jobs_wildcard
```

I have this code which works great for pulling single jobs, but I would like to modify it to use wildcards and pull all the pipeline jobs in the `<repo>/jobs/*` path.

My script:

```
pipelineJob("App/App Server Stop") {
  definition {
    cpsScm {
      scm {
        git {
          remote {
            url("https://gitlab.domain.com/repo/project.git")
            credentials("<git_creds_id>")
          }
          branch('develop')
        }
      }
      scriptPath("jobs/app_server_stop")
    }
  }
  triggers {
    scm('H/15 * * * *')
  }
}
```

I have looked at may example on the internet that have gigantic code or pieces of code but being as I am not a programmer I am lost as to what I need to do.

Can I not modify the above slightly to pull in all the jobs under that path? Am I way off? Can I do something like this:

```
pipelineJob("App/*") {
  definition {
    cpsScm {
      scm {
        git {
          remote {
            url("https://gitlab.domain.com/repo/project.git")
            credentials("<git_creds_id>")
          }
          branch('develop')
        }
      }
      scriptPath("jobs/*")
    }
  }
  triggers {
    scm('H/15 * * * *')
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What I can advise is to add following script to your CaaC:

```
jobs:
- script: >
    freeStyleJob('job-dsl-plugin') {
      description('Initial job to setup all pipelines with DSL')
      displayName('Seed job')
      label('seed-job-agent')
      scm {
        git {
          extensions {
            cloneOptions {
              depth(1)
              shallow(true)
              noTags(true)
              timeout(10)
            }
            gitLFSPull()
          }
          remote {
            credentials('git-token')
            url('https://git.xyz.com/xyz/project.git')
          }
          branch('*/main')
        }
      }
      steps {
        jobDsl {
          removedJobAction('DELETE')
          removedViewAction('DELETE')
          targets('jobs/*.groovy')
        }
      }
      triggers {
        hudsonStartupTrigger {
          label('')
          quietPeriod('0')
          nodeParameterName('')
          runOnChoice('') 
        }
      }
    }
```

This will create job that will connect to `git` repo and load all files from `jobs` directory with extension `.groovy`.

In my example I am also using [startup trigger](https://plugins.jenkins.io/startup-trigger-plugin/) plugin which will run this job after each `Jenkins` restart.

I would not advise using `cron` trigger since this job will fail if there will be some running job.